# How to remove black edges between spherical shell?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am interested to know how to make the concentric shell smoother. This is what I have now:

[image]

This is the code i used to generate that image:

```
SetOptions[{SphericalPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D}, Mesh -> None];
fun = {r {Sin[t], -Cos[t], 0}};
p1 = SphericalPlot3D[{3}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}, {\[Phi], -Pi, Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
p2 = SphericalPlot3D[{20, 21}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}, {\[Phi], -Pi,Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
p4 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 0, 3}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
p3 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 3, 11}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
p11 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 11, 14}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
p14 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 14, 16}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
p16 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 16, 19}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
p19 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 19, 21}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},PlotStyle -> Directive[Pink, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p11, p14, p16, p19, ViewPoint -> {-1.96178, -2.70966, -6.17715}, 
ViewVertical -> {0.326362, -0.0669218, 0.942873}, PlotRange -> All, 
ImageSize -> Large, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it is faster to write your own function that creates the points for the rings in 3D

```
disk3d[{r1_, r2_}] := With[{dphi = 2. Pi/50},
  Table[
   {
      r1 {Cos[phi], Sin[phi], 0}, 
      r2 {Cos[phi], Sin[phi], 0}, 
      r2 {Cos[phi + dphi], Sin[phi + dphi], 0}, 
      r1 {Cos[phi + dphi], Sin[phi + dphi], 0}
   }, {phi, 0, 2 Pi - dphi, dphi}]
  ]
```

And then you can use

```
p2 = SphericalPlot3D[{20, 21}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}, {\[Phi], -Pi, Pi},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[1], Specularity[]]];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], {#1, Polygon[disk3d[#2]]} & @@@ {
    {Blue, {0, 3}}, 
    {White,{3, 11}},
    {Orange, {11, 14}},
    {Red, {14, 16}},
    {Yellow, {16, 19}},
    {Pink, {19, 21}}},
    First[p2]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks very much @halirutan. I am not much familiar with mathematica so i didn't understand the logic. I tried your solution in my machine but the image is not as much smooth as you provided in your solution. you can see output of my machine here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86562049/final.png

Comment: This is really only the rendering (except of the mesh for the half sphere, which I don't know why it is shown in your case). Can you check your *Antialiasing Quality*? You find it when you go to Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics. Set it to highest quality and check again.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a higher number of PlotPoints to reduce the jagged look of the shells.

```
SetOptions[{SphericalPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 50];
```

Comment: Nice, but then it quits the Kernel (Mma 10.0.2.0, OSX).